# Do methods ending with _! have a special meaning in Scala?

Tags: scala, naming-conventions

Do methods ending with `_!` such as `delete_!` or `i_is_!` have a special meaning? Are they "just names"? Do they follow some convention? There's even `bulkDelete_!!`. (The specific context is Lift if it makes a difference.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure what the convention is for using `_!` and `_!!` in Lift, but here's a bit of background.

Any alphanumeric identifier can have _ and a list of symbols added and still be parsed as a single identifier.  For example:

```
scala> class Example_!@%*!
defined class Example_$bang$at$percent$times$bang
```

(In fact, you can parse almost anything as an identifier if you surround it with backticks--and this is what you do if a Java class uses a Scala reserved word, for example.  Or if you want spaces in your identifiers.)

The compiler only recognizes one symbolic ending specially, however.  If there is a method that looks like a getter, then getter_= will be interpreted as a setter.  (Whether you actually *use* it as a setter is up to you; it will have the semantics of a setter, anyway.)  So

```
scala> class Q { def q = "Hi"; def q_=(s: String) { println(s.reverse) } }
defined class Q

scala> val q = new Q
q: Q = Q@b5c12e

scala> q.q
res0: java.lang.String = Hi

scala> q.q = "Could use this to set something"
gnihtemos tes ot siht esu dluoC
```

In addition, the compiler reverses the order of caller and callee in *any* method that ends in `:`.  This is most often seen in lists: `newElement :: existingList` is actually a call to `existingList.::(newElement)`.  So, for example:

```
scala> object Caps { def to_:(s: String) = s.toUpperCase }
defined module Caps

scala> "Example" to_: Caps
res40: java.lang.String = EXAMPLE
```

Any other usage of `_` + symbols is convention.

Comment: `_` is used to separate groups of word characters from symbol characters. So `foo_!!_bar` is a legal identifier. If you don't want to follow this rule, or need to use a reserved word, you can also enclose it in backticks. This is useful for calling java methods named `type`, for example.

Comment: @retronym - Good point about backticks; I'll add that.  Try typing `val foo_!!_bar = 0` into the REPL, though....

Comment: Oh wow, my mental parser is out of sync with the spec. Please ignore. Identifers are basically `\w[\w\d]*(_([:opchar:]*))`

Comment: Mhh, So, I understand that it is not possible to type for instance `def sort!( ... ` but you would have to use: `def sort_!(...` is that correct?

Comment: @S-mSO - That's right.  `def sort!()` is invalid.  `def sort_!()` is fine.

Comment: @retronym: more like `\w[\w\d]*(_([:opchar:]*))?|[:opchar:]+` I think (including $ but this one is reserved). Also I just found out that // and /* cannot be operators...

Answer (score 9):

There are no special meanings to the ! in Scala names.  In the family of Lisp-based languages, ! is often used to indicate that a function is has side-effects, and that looks to be the convention here.

Comment: Another similar convention is to use to use zero parameter lists for side-effect free functions, and one empty parameter list for others. e.g. `gun.model` vs `gun.fire()`

Comment: Ruby uses `!` for *side effects*  also

Answer (score 6):

Strangely unmentioned thus far (though not particularly relevant to your question) is unary_! which is treated specially.

```
scala> class A { def unary_! = 5 }
defined class A

scala> !(new A)
res0: Int = 5
```

Comment: It has more to do with unary_ then ! in the end. You can have unary_+ for example